# Why is it that I can import LambdaStep when I run my notebook locally but not when I run it in Sagemaker studio?

Tags: aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have been struggling to run this code snippet in my Jupyter notebook in Sagemaker studio when I can run it locally. I previously imported Sagemaker. I can import Sagemaker smoothly and I pip installed it previously.

```
from sagemaker.workflow.lambda_step import LambdaStep
```

Here's the error thrown when I attempted to run it:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker.workflow.lambda_step'
```

I also tried different ways of importing such as 'from sagemaker.workflow import lambda_step' or 'sagemaker.workflow.lambda_step.LambdaStep' straight away when calling the function. Those ways also did not help me.

I'm also not sure why I can't import LambdaStep when I can run the code snippet below smoothly in Sagemaker studio:

```
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline import Pipeline
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem and would greatly appreciate if someone can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, my issue is solved after I installed sagemaker again but by using this code snippet

```
!pip install -U sagemaker
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time the question was posted, `sagemaker.workflow.lambda_step` was very new. Most likely, the OP's SageMaker Studio environment had not been updated in a while (here are the [update instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-tasks-update.html)). Lambda steps were only released on [SageMaker Python SDK 2.51](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/releases/tag/v2.51.0), and importing from a previous SDK version would fail.

Without updating a kernel, all packages in it will remain on the version they were when the kernel was launched. A possible workaround is to force an update by using `pip install -U`.